# If I use ZFC as a metatheory for FOL, doesn't it make it weaker?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory, nonstandard-models

Basically, there is a theorem of first-order logic that says that no L-structure whose domain is infinite can be axiomatized up to isomorphism, so in particular there is no set $\Phi$ of formulas that attempts to axiomatize first-order arithmetic where all structure $\mathfrak{A}$ such that $\mathfrak{A}\vDash\Phi$ is isomorphic. Because of this, we know that there are non-isomorphic models that satisfy the Peano axioms. But by choosing a model $M\vDash\text{ZFC}$ we know that $M$ manages to prove that every (internal, i.e., in $M$) Peano structure that satisfies all $\Phi$ are isomorphic, which is an idiosyncrasy of each $\text{ZFC}$ model. So basically each $M$ thinks they have the canonical structure of arithmetic, whereas between them these are non-isomorphic, but this can only be seen "from the outside", therefore there are at least as many $\text{ZFC}$ models as non-isomorphic Peano arithmetic models.

So this is where my doubt arises, if the models of Peano arithmetic that I can build in any $\text{ZFC}$ model is always a subset of all Peano structures, then using ZFC as a metatheory to do first-order logic does not mean that I'll be doing a less expressive first-order logic? Or less powerful in some sense, since I'm never going to be able to build these non-standard models of arithmetic, or at least, the non-isomorphism between them?

Comment: It is the second order axiomatization of number theory that has a unique model up to isomorphism (according to any model of ZFC), not the first order one. Any model of ZFC believes there are a proper class of models of first order PA, since that statement is provable in ZFC.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yes, my problem is exactly there, the ZFC manages to prove that every first-order PA model is isomorphic, while the FOL does not, but one is used as a metatheory to define the other, doesn't that create a problem?

Comment: Did you read what I wrote? No it doesn’t.

Comment: I should be more specific: “no it doesn’t”=“no, ZFC absolutely does not prove that every first order pa model is isomorphic”. It proves the opposite of that

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Sorry, I expressed myself wrong, the ZFC only proves within the model that all peano structures are isomorphic, but wouldn't using one of these models as a metatheory for FOL generate the same problem?

Comment: I don’t know what “only proves within the model” means, but it sounds like the wrong idea too. Every model of ZFC contains many non isomorphic models of first order PA.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Can you point me to some good reference on the subject? I'm currently just reading ebbinghaus

Comment: I wouldn’t expect ebbinghaus to say anything outright wrong on this subject… perhaps if you give the passage that gave you that impression someone could clear up the confusion. I don’t know of a good reference offhand on this specifically. Generally on the model theory of arithmetic, Kaye’s book is good and introductory. The point here though is that if ZFC proves something, it’s true in every model of ZFC, and ZFC proves Lowenheim Skolem, etc.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen In chapter VII.4, section 4.2, Ebbinghaus builds a ZFC model B whose set ω is uncountable (outside the model) and countable (in the model interpretation) and another ZFC countable model A, thereby showing that (1) the ω in B is not isomorphic to the ω in A and (2) ZFC ⊢ Dedekind's theorem, and he explains: "However, (1) and (2) do not contradict each other. (2) merely says that in each individual model ℭ of ZFC every two Peano structures are isomorphic (in the sense of ℭ), whereas (1) speaks of Peano structures in different models of ZFC." say with "inside the model"

Comment: That's what I mean by "within the model". However, in section 4.3 he uses ZFC as a metatheory to define FOL, but doesn't that imply that this FOL would also believe that every inner PS is isomorphic?

Comment: The confusion I think is what is meant by “Peano Structure”. It does not mean “model of (first order) PA”. It means “model of the second order Peano axioms”. ZFC does prove that the second order axioms have a unique model.